# display locationquanityavailable on Netsuite Sitebuilder Site

Tags: netsuite

Trying to figure out how to set the location of a multi-location Netsuite so that on the web store it only will display the quantity of that location only. Currently it displays ALL locations (sums).

I would like js in the header possibly that will set the location to one location and then when using locationquantityavailable it will grab that locations quantity and displays it.

Anyone been able to display just a locations quantity?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your locations as making their inventory available in the web store. Then the standard sitebuilder tags `quantityavailable` and `quantityonhand` will pull from those.

If that doesn't work you could manage this by various forms of scripting.

1. Script your inventory affecting transactions so that inventory changes from the desired locations update custom item fields.
2. Create a Suitelet that takes a page's item ids as a query string and returns current inventory for those items.
3. create a non-stored custom item field that populates with the results of a saved search. I doubt this option will work in the context of the web store but it's very low effort to check. Search for "Creating Custom Fields with Values Derived from Summary Search Results" in the Netsuite online help for details.

I've used the first two of these in production to achieve the result you're looking for.

each of these has advantages and disadvantages so there's a trade off between how busy your back-end is vs how busy the site is.

Comment: The location is already marked as available in the web store. The ones we don't want to show are NOT marked that way. Yet, NS sums all and displays the sum vs just the location.

Comment: It's been a while since I tried the simple configuration options. too bad it doesn't work. Check out the other options.

Comment: Yes, the simple checkbox to display it or not doesn't work. It sums all the quantities.